# How to change timezone in http response (django server)?

Tags: python, django, http, datetime, timezone

I'm running django server without any proxy:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:80
```

I set my local timezone on linux server, it's correct:

```
root@83b3bf90b5c5:/app# date
Fri Apr  7 12:38:42 MSK 2017
```

Also I set local timezone on settings.py of my django project:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Moscow'
```

And checked it:

```
>>> from django.utils.timezone import localtime, now
>>> localtime(now())
datetime.datetime(2017, 4, 7, 12, 38, 42, 196476, 
tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Moscow' MSK+3:00:00 STD>)
```

But when I open any webpage from client (Google Chrome browser) - in http response headers timezone isn't local:

```
Date:Fri, 07 Apr 2017 09:38:42 GMT
```

How can I change timezone in http headers for all project globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I change timezone in http headers for all project globally?

HTTP date headers are [defined](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1) as being in UTC (represented for historical reasons by the characters `GMT`), so neither Django nor any other server or framework will allow you to localize them to your time zone. Is there a reason you want to do that?

Django does have a means for switching to a local time zone (see [activate()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.activate)), but that is only for application-specific content, not HTTP headers.

Comment: Thank you, there no reason to localize them. I just want to find out why they are in UTC. Your answer and IETF reference helped.

Answer (score 1):

Using [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/), as `astimezone` method

```
from pytz import timezone

time_zone = timezone(settings.TIME_ZONE)
currentTime = currentTime.astimezone(time_zone)
```

> In your Middleware:

```
import pytz

from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin

class TimezoneMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
    def process_request(self, request):
        tzname = request.session.get('django_timezone')
        if tzname:
            timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(tzname))
        else:
            timezone.deactivate()
```

> In Your view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

def set_timezone(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.session['django_timezone'] = request.POST['timezone']
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'template.html', {'timezones': pytz.common_timezones})
```

> In your templete.html

```
{% load tz %}
{% get_current_timezone as TIME_ZONE %}
<form action="{% url 'set_timezone' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="timezone">Time zone:</label>
    <select name="timezone">
        {% for tz in timezones %}
        <option value="{{ tz }}"{% if tz == TIME_ZONE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ tz }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Set" />
</form>
```

Comment: Where I should put this code? And what is currentTime variable which referenced in assignment?

Comment: @xtdwps: I have updated the answer please have a look

Comment: Link to official Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/